# Using Where method in Linq 2 Entities with OR clause

Tags: linq-to-entities

I want to use Where method in Linq 2 entities that will be equal to this

```
userRepository.Users.Where(u=>u.RoleID == 1 || u=>u.RoldID == 2).Select(o => new SelectListItem { Text = o.Role.RoleName, Value = o.RoleID.ToString() }).ToList();
```

The problem of course is in **Where(u=>u.RoleID == 1 || u=>u.RoldID == 2)**

The problem is that I don't know how to use WHERE method with OR inside the WHERE clause.

any ideas (the code above will not compile of-course b/c of the lambda expression.

userRepository.Users returns an list of Users entities.

I guess that and can be done using concatenation of .Where().Where() but I need an OR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the extra u=>

```
Where(u => u.RoleID == 1 || u.RoleID == 2).
```

In your code, you try to "or" the lambdas, "lambda1 OR lambda2", this is not possible as you've noticed.
You can however "or" the expression inside the lambda:

lambda(expression1 OR expression2)

Read the code as:

(User user)
{
   return user.RoleId == 1 || user.RoleId == 2;
}

If that makes things clearer..

Also, I guess you have a typo on the last part "u.RoldId == 2", instead of RoleId..

Comment: Thanks, so simple, yet, who would know... ;-) The typo was in the edit.. I rewrite to remove enums, and make it shorter. but the extra u=> was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Where uses an generic anonymous delegate, in this case Func.

What that means is: "given a user return a boolean", or "given a user, supply a criteria to determine if I should select that user".

With a lambda expression, you only have to define the variable your "given" once.

The basic syntax is

```
variableName => expression
```

in this case we have

```
u => (expression)
```

where u is a User and (expression) is an expression that evaluates to a boolean.

```
Where(u => (u.RoleID==1 || u.RoleID==2))
```

(which as Roger pointed out while I was finishing this post is the correct answer)

doing an AND, or any other logical comparison would be exactly the same

```
Where(u=> u.Name.Equals(userName) && u.Email.Equals(email))
```

You can have any expression, the only requirement is that it returns a boolean. Even if an expression that ignores the variable you given that is fine.

```
Where(u=> true)
```

This would select all users, while probably pointless it demonstrates the structure of a lambda expression.

EDIT: Didn't see the additional information that Roger's edit had supplied which probably explained this better than I, till I made this post, sorry for the duplication.